# jQuery is not available in ASP.NET Core 2.2 Razor view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core

I created a simple ASP .Net Core (version 2.2) Web Application (non-MVC) in Visual Studio 2017 Community (Version 15.9.6)

By default, jQuery (version 3.3.1) is included in the wwwroot/lib/jquery directory.

I am getting jQuery IntelliSense.

jQuery is referenced in the default /Pages/Shared_Layout.cshtml file correctly.

I added the following code to the default.csthml page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $("p").click(function () {
             $(this).hide();
         });
     });
</script>

<p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
<p>Click me away!</p>
<p>Click me too!</p>
```

This simple code does not work by default.

I do not understand why.

**Console Error**

```
0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined
```

**Markup**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - jQueryTest2</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" /> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <header></header> 
    <div class="container"> 
        <main role="main"> @RenderBody() </main> 
    </div> 
    <footer></footer> 
    <environment exclude="Development"> 
        <script src="cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/>
    </environment>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Anything showing up in the JavaScript console?

Comment: I get the following error on the $(document).ready...

`0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined`

This would appear to indicate that jQuery is not referenced correctly.  However the default ASP .Net Core template in Visual Studio does reference jQuery

Comment: Can you show us more of the markup?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - jQueryTest2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <header></header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>
    <footer></footer>
   <environment exclude="Development">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       </environment>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Apologies, I cannot figure out how to <pre> the code...

Comment: For large pieces of code its better to update your question.

Comment: What you've shown is Shared_Layout.cshtml?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First add `@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)` at the bottom of the `body` of your `Layout.cshtml` page.

Then your scripts inside `@section Scripts` as follows:

```
@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
           $("p").click(function () {
             $(this).hide();
           });
       });
    </script>
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem!

Comment: This is what I've always done but the markup they posted doesn't have that setup.

Comment: Yes! Without this set up `jQuery `would not be available on that page.

Comment: Just to clarify... the @section Scripts{} should go on the index.cshtml, and not the _Layout page?  Thanks!

Comment: Yes!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment we can see that jQuery has not actually loaded by the time this script element is run. Typically you need to load jQuery in the `head` element to make sure it is available for `script` elements defined in the `body`.